# How can I do it : When checked radio button change input required?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I need help. I have 3 radio button 1. Credit Cart 2. Cargo Payment
3. Bank Payment

So I want when checked id ="credit" (Credit Cart) : Credit cart information inputs to be required with JS.

When the selected Radio button becomes credit card, the card information is opened. No card payment is required when others are selected. Therefore, it will be mandatory to enter information only when cart is selected.

```js
$('input[name="cname"]').change(function() {
  if ($("#kart").is(':checked')) {
    $('#cname').add.attr('required');
    $('#cnumber').add.attr('required');
    $('#cmonth').add.attr('required');
    $('#cyear').add.attr('required');
    $('#ccvc').add.attr('required');
  } else {
    $('#cname').removeAttr('required');
    $('#cnumber').removeAttr('required');
    $('#cmonth').removeAttr('required');
    $('#cyear').removeAttr('required');
    $('#ccvc').removeAttr('required');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-block my-3">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="kart">
    <input id="credit" name="paymentType" checked type="radio" value="Kredi Kartı" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="credit">Paiement par carte Kreadi</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="kapida">
    <input id="cargo" name="paymentType" type="radio" value="Kapıda Ödeme" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="cargo">Payer à la Porte</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="havale">
    <input id="bank" name="paymentType" type="radio" value="Banka Havale" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="bank">Paiement par Virement Bancaire</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="kartodeme">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label for="">Nom et Prénom Sur la Carte</label>
        <input type="text" name="cname" class="form-control" id="cname" placeholder="Prénom / Nom de Famille">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label for="">Numéro de Carte</label>
        <input type="text" name="cnumber" min="16" max="16" class="form-control" id="cnumber" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
        <label for="">Date d'expiration</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="">Lune</label>
        <select name="cmonth" id="cmonth" class="form-control">
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
          <option value="04">04</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="06">06</option>
          <option value="07">07</option>
          <option value="08">08</option>
          <option value="09">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="">An</label>
        <select name="cyear" id="cyear" class="form-control">
          <option value="20">2020</option>
          <option value="21">2021</option>
          <option value="22">2022</option>
          <option value="23">2023</option>
          <option value="24">2024</option>
          <option value="25">2025</option>
          <option value="26">2026</option>
          <option value="27">2027</option>
          <option value="28">2028</option>
          <option value="29">2029</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="">CVC</label>
        <input type="text" name="ccvc" class="form-control" id="ccvc" placeholder="123">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML

Comment: `.add.attr('required');` is not valid JS

Comment: My 2 Inputs : <div class="row">  
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                            <label for="">Nom et Prénom Sur la Carte</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cname" class="form-control" id="cname" placeholder="Prénom / Nom de Famille" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

Comment: You have 5  - please add to the snippet instead of commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

- You want to run on click of the radio
- You want to test credit and not kart
- To validate a select, it needs an empty `<option value="">Month</option>`

```js
const cc = () => {
  const checked = $("#credit").is(':checked');
  ['cnumber', 'cmonth', 'cyear', 'ccvc', 'cname'].forEach(ele => {
    $ele = $("#" + ele);
    if ($ele.length > 0) { // test if the element exists
      if (checked) $ele.attr("required", true);
      else $ele.removeAttr("required");
    }
  })
};
$('[name=paymentType]').on('click', cc)
cc(); // on load

// extra code to generate the years from current year
const year = +String(new Date().getFullYear()).slice(2);
let curMonth = new Date().getMonth()+1;
$("#cyear")[0].options.length=1; // remove all but one
for (let i=year, n = year+9; i<=n;i++) {
  $("#cyear").append($('<option/>',{text:i,value:i}));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-block my-3">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="kart">
    <input id="credit" name="paymentType" checked type="radio" value="Kredi Kartı" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="credit">Paiement par carte Kreadi</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="kapida">
    <input id="cargo" name="paymentType" type="radio" value="Kapıda Ödeme" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="cargo">Payer à la Porte</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio" id="havale">
    <input id="bank" name="paymentType" type="radio" value="Banka Havale" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="bank">Paiement par Virement Bancaire</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="kartodeme">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label for="">Nom et Prénom Sur la Carte</label>
        <input type="text" name="cname" class="form-control" id="cname" placeholder="Prénom / Nom de Famille">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label for="">Numéro de Carte</label>
        <input type="text" name="cnumber" min="16" max="16" class="form-control" id="cnumber" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
        <label>Date d'expiration <input type="date" /></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <select name="cmonth" id="cmonth" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Lune</option>
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
          <option value="04">04</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="06">06</option>
          <option value="07">07</option>
          <option value="08">08</option>
          <option value="09">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <select name="cyear" id="cyear" class="form-control">
          <option value="">An</option>
          <option value="20">2020</option>
          <option value="21">2021</option>
          <option value="22">2022</option>
          <option value="23">2023</option>
          <option value="24">2024</option>
          <option value="25">2025</option>
          <option value="26">2026</option>
          <option value="27">2027</option>
          <option value="28">2028</option>
          <option value="29">2029</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="ccvc">CVC</label>
        <input type="text" name="ccvc" class="form-control" id="ccvc" placeholder="123">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for answer but dont work :( ... should be (required = "" ) in inputs or not ?

Comment: @LingoonTechnology It did not work because you had errors in your code. It is "credit" and not "kart" and you want to change when the user clicks the payment type, not when they change the name

Comment: PS: You need a "please select" with an empty option to validate the selects!

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't so clear, but if you are trying to enforce validation when `#credit` radio is checked you can approach it as follows:

1. Store a variable, let's call it `const isValidationRequired = false`;
2. Have event listeners on all radio inputs. Let's say you add a class radios-wrapper on the parent div, so select the following:

`

```
function handleRadioClick(e) {
    const targetId = e.target.id;
    if (targetId == "credit") {
        isValidationRequired = true;
    }
}

const radiosWrapper = document.querySelector('.radios-wrapper');
const radios = radiosWrapper.querySelectorAll('input[type='radio']');
radios.forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('click', handleRadioClick))
```